# Change value of first input by changing value of second input

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to change input value by changing other input .Basically, i mean how can I bind two input together by using each loop for getting both inputs

Comment: Hello, can you please put some code, which you have tried ?

Answer (score 2):

To change another input field based on current you can try

```
$('#FirstInputID').change(function() {
    $('#SecondInputID').val($(this).val());
});
```